# How to remove all the markers in FCTB (Fast color Text Box) Quickly?

Tags: c#, fctb

I am using below code to remove the markers on a tab , but it is taking a while to clear them for a long page.

Can somebody please suggest a faster way.

```
 int iRows = ft.CurrentTB.LineInfos.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= iRows; i++)
        {
            CurrentTB[i].BackgroundBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
            CurrentTB.Selection.Start = new Place(1, i);
            CurrentTB.DoSelectionVisible();
            CurrentTB.Invalidate();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faster solution is as below:

```
int iRows = ft.CurrentTB.LineInfos.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= iRows; i++)
    {
        CurrentTB[i].BackgroundBrush = Brushes.Transparent;         
        CurrentTB.DoSelectionVisible();
   }
            CurrentTB.Select();
            CurrentTB.DoSelectionVisible();
```